# "летящий" versus "летающий"

Tags: словоупотребление, глаголы

I have always considered **летающий** the derived adjective/active participle of **летать**. However, today I came across the following passage:

> В него попал какой-то **летящий** обломок.

*He was pelted by some piece of flying debris*.

Are they in fact interchangeable, or is this a typo? If not, what is the difference, if any, in their usage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Летающий* and *летящий* are formed from two different verbs: *летать* and *лететь* (the former being an iterative for the latter).

It's similar to English "sniffle / sniff, shuffle / shove" etc.

However, this particular iterative participle also acquired an idiomatic meaning: it means not only "flying repeatedly" but also "able to fly".

Adjectives meaning "able to" or "inherently doing smth." are in number of cases formed by using suffix *-уч/-юч*: *горючий / горящий, кипучий / кипящий, гремучий / гремящий* etc., *летучий / летящий* being no exception.

So *летающий* has two meanings:

1. Adjective "able to fly", synonymous to *летучий*: *летающая тарелка* "flying saucer", *летающая крепость* "flying fortress".
2. Participle "flying repeatedly or continuously": *Летающий в ночи* "The Night Flier", *часто летающий пассажир* "frequent flier" etc.

*Летящий* is a participle meaning "flying at the moment": *астероид, летящий по направлению к Земле* "an asteroid flying towards Earth".

Answer (score 5):

`Летящий` - means flying right now.
Examples:

> Летящий обломок
>   Самолет, летящий в южном направлении

---

`Летающий` - means able to fly.
Examples:

> Летающий кран
>   Самолет, ежедневно летающий по маршруту Москва - Нью-Йорк

Comment: Thank you. However, by your definition, I would expect it to be: самолет, ежеднвно летящий по маршруту Москва - Нью-Йорк,since it currently flies that route, no?

Comment: @CocoPop - _Летающий_ can also mean "flying there and back, flying back and forth": У меня есть друг, часто летающий в Лондон, and also "flying around": Вороны, летающие над лесом, громко каркали.

Comment: @CocoPop No. `ежедневно` means _everyday_ and it doesn't imply that it flies _right now_.